# Interactive messages in slack

Tags: php, bots, slack-api

I am trying to use interactive messages in slack. I have already set up my incoming webhook, but every time that i try to use buttons this is what slack sends to my Request URL:

Input:

[image]

Output:
[image]

Slack is sending me this output whenever a select a button. What can i do to revert this. By the way i am working in php.

Comment: `html_entity_decode()`?

Comment: The thing is that i dont understand why am i receiving the payload directly on slack

Comment: @Ana they're just doing a simple encoding before transferring so user's message does not interfere with their own coding/json structure maybe?

Comment: @mehulmpt I know how to decode the payload that i receive. what is happening is that the payload you see on the output tag is going to my slack channel.